# Bringing COM library's dialogs to front

Tags: windows, winapi

I am creating a Windows app that hosts some ActiveX libraries. My app does not have any GUI, but those ActiveX (or probably more accurate plain COM) libraries can have their own GUI. Problem is, the dialogs of those libraries do not come into foreground, but are rather hidden behind other windows on the screen. What can I do in my app to enable those other forms to properly come into foreground? I don't even have their HWND handles, because I just call some function of some COM object. My app is written in C#, but I can accept C++ answers as well. This is a Windows API issue.

This question is loosely related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75314202/395718).

Comment: It's the responsibility of these COM objects ("ActiveX" was a marketing name, it's more or less OLE/COM +/- some extra interfaces) to integrate properly into the host. One cannot show a window and expect it will fit nicely with surroundings w/o some effort. If you have the source you can do something otherwise, you'll have to get their handle somehow and hack something (using UI Automation for example). Your question is missing details, code, reproducing sample, etc. for a more useful answer.

Comment: It requires breaking stringent UI rules, luckily enshrined in everybody's favorite [utility library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.appactivate?view=net-7.0).  It even finds the window for you.  The window must be active when you call it so you probably need a timer.

Answer (score -2):

In the end I went with borderless, "taskbarless", tiny window, placed at negative desktop coordinates. This window serves as a parent for any window that COM objects may show. Parent must be visible, but I don't want users to see it, hence the need for negative desktop coordinates.

Comment: That doesn't help any. All this does is delegate the *"force into the foreground"* operation to a different window. The problem hasn't changed.

Comment: It helps me very much so. We may have different understanding of what the problem is. For me the problem is that it doesn't work the way I want it to work. When I apply my solution it works just the way I want it. And on fundamental level the solution is correct. COM objects expect a parent window in the same process, so that they create their dialogs as children of it. If parent window is missing then these dialogs become children of the Desktop window. Not what I want, regardless of the "no focus" issue.

Comment: Presumably, those ActiveX controls require an *owner* (not a parent). An owner/owned relationship establishes a relative Z-order between windows. The owned window's position in the Z-order is always relative to that of the owner window. Once you manage to push your (invisible) owner window far enough back, the problem you set out to solve will return.

Comment: Who will push the window? It is not visible to the user. It is brought to foreground initially, or shall we say before I call the COM function.

Comment: *"Who will push the window?"* - The system, on behalf of the user that decided to bring an other window into the foreground.

Comment: So, COM window will be pushed behind the window that user wants focused, just as planned. And user may bring the COM window back into focus, just as planned. Meanwhile, the hidden taskbarless owner window will happily stay hidden, just outside the desktop area. I see no downside to any of this.

Comment: What is the use case that I won't be happy about?

Comment: *"user may bring the COM window back into focus"* - Unless the dialog is still partially visible, a user cannot easily bring it to the foreground. Which is exactly the same situation you started out with.

Comment: What do you mean? The COM dialog is available from the taskbar, and also from Alt+Tab. Only the hidden owner window is actually hidden.